# Is there any method to save coordinates as attribute of span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery("#form_panel").hide();

    $('#addTag').on('click', function(e) { //creates span dynamically
        $('#demo').append('<span class="tags" id="' + $('#title').val() + '" data-y="' + 'pos_y' + '" data-x="' + 'pos_x' + '">' + $('#title').val() + ', </span>');
        console.log("#addTag'");
        console.log(pos_x);
        console.log(pos_y);

    });


    jQuery(".tags").live("mouseover", function() {
        // $(this).find(".tagged_box").css("background-color","yellow");
        console.log("mouseover");
        console.log(this.id);
        console.log(pos_y);
        console.log(this.data - y); // NaN
        //over();


    });
})
```

this is my piece of code and for console.log(this.data-y); it is giving NaN, rest code is working properly. (pos_x and pos_y are numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to save some data in span.For that you can use data attribute of html5 regarding how to do it, check out this example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data).Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so much, but I want to save two numbers,for example 25 and 50 instead of simply "bird" in data-animal-type="bird" . So how I can do that?

Comment: you can save any number for your case you can do it  like data-coord-x='25' and data-coord-y='50'.You can name them as per your choice just prepend "data-"

Comment: Thanks. I got that. But now I am getting problem to create multiple span dynamically. Means, whenever I will enter text, a new span will be created and text will be in that span. Will you help me in this matter also?

Comment: I will do my best to help but I am now not clear about what problem you are facing .Please explain a bit in detail preferably with some code or you can also create a jsfiddle file so that I can understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I have used further code for creating dynamic spans and I want to get id of those spans using 
jQuery("#demo").live("mouseover",function(){});

here is my code-->>

$('#addTag').on('click',function (e) {  //creates span dynamicaly
       $('#demo').append('<span id="'+$('#title').val()+'">'+$('#title').val()+',</span>');
    });

Comment: try something like this '$("#demo:last-child span")'.let me know if this is giving you in-correct results,then please share a jsfiddle or jsbin file so that I can take a look at the whole code.

Comment: here it is giving me error
$('#demo').append('<span class="tags" id="'+$('#title').val()+'" data-y="'+'pos_y'+'" data-x="'+'pos_x'+'">'+$('#title').val()+', </span>');

in console.log it is giving me that data-y and data-y is NaN

Comment: I got the following result when i used data-y="10" data-x="11"    <span class="tags" id="sad" data-y="10" data-x="11">sad, </span> I think you have problem with the scope of the pos_x and pos_y.Moreover I used $('.test#abc') or $('#abc') and got the results note abc here is the id of the span.Sorry for the late reply.Hope you get it working now.Also take a look at .data() docs are here(http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I checked the scope is not the problem the syntax is the problem.Check the syntax

Comment: yes, it was syntax problem. Now I am sharing my code which is not working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery("#form_panel").hide();
  jQuery('#addTag').on('click',function (e) {  //creates span dynamically
    var append_string = '<span class="tags" id="'+jQuery('#title').val()+'" data-y="'+y_pos+'" data-x="'+x_pos+'">'+jQuery('#title').val()+', </span>'
    jQuery('#demo').append(append_string);
  });
  jQuery(".tags").live("mouseover",function(){
    var ids = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var x_cord = jQuery(this).attr('data-x');
    var y_cord = jQuery(this).attr('data-y');
    console.log("mouseover");console.log(ids);
    console.log(x_cord);console.log(y_cord);
    jQuery("#overshow").css({top: y_cord, left: x_cord, width:'100px', height:'100px', position:'absolute',border:'3px solid gray'});                   
    jQuery('#overshow').show('fast').delay(1000).hide('slow');
  });       
});
```

I have declared two variables, x_pos and y_pos, outside jQuery(window).load(function(){}); which are accessible to all functions in .